# Sending an Adaptive Card on bot startup as the welcome message

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

I have some code for the bot to send a message (string) on start up.

However, instead of sending text like you see in the code below.  I am trying to figure out how you would send an Adaptive Card in this case.  I have sent a Card from the RootDialog before, but not from the MessageController.cs.   Any direction would be great here!

```
else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
            {
                // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
                // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
                // Not available in all channels

                IConversationUpdateActivity iConversationUpdated = message as IConversationUpdateActivity;
                if (iConversationUpdated != null)
                {
                    ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(message.ServiceUrl));

                    foreach (var member in iConversationUpdated.MembersAdded ?? System.Array.Empty<ChannelAccount>())
                    {
                        // if the bot is added, then
                        if (member.Id == iConversationUpdated.Recipient.Id)
                        {
                            var reply = ((Activity)iConversationUpdated).CreateReply($"WELCOME MESSAGE HERE");
                            await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the code snippet you provided you should be able to copy and paste this to replace it.  More information about cards in bot framework can be found [in this blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-rich-card-attachments)

```
       else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            IConversationUpdateActivity iConversationUpdated = message as IConversationUpdateActivity;
            if (iConversationUpdated != null)
            {
                ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(message.ServiceUrl));

                foreach (var member in iConversationUpdated.MembersAdded ?? System.Array.Empty<ChannelAccount>())
                {
                    // if the bot is added, then
                    if (member.Id == iConversationUpdated.Recipient.Id)
                    {

                        Activity replyToConversation = message.CreateReply("Should go to conversation");
                        replyToConversation.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

                        AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard();

                        // Specify speech for the card.
                        card.Speak = "<s>Your  meeting about \"Adaptive Card design session\"<break strength='weak'/> is starting at 12:30pm</s><s>Do you want to snooze <break strength='weak'/> or do you want to send a late notification to the attendees?</s>";

                        // Add text to the card.
                        card.Body.Add(new TextBlock()
                        {
                            Text = "Adaptive Card design session",
                            Size = TextSize.Large,
                            Weight = TextWeight.Bolder
                        });
                        // Add text to the card.
                        card.Body.Add(new TextBlock()
                        {
                            Text = "Conf Room 112/3377 (10)"
                        });
                        // Add text to the card.
                        card.Body.Add(new TextBlock()
                        {
                            Text = "12:30 PM - 1:30 PM"
                        });
                        // Add list of choices to the card.
                        card.Body.Add(new ChoiceSet()
                        {
                            Id = "snooze",
                            Style = ChoiceInputStyle.Compact,
                            Choices = new List<Choice>()
                            {
                                new Choice() { Title = "5 minutes", Value = "5", IsSelected = true },
                                new Choice() { Title = "15 minutes", Value = "15" },
                                new Choice() { Title = "30 minutes", Value = "30" }
                            }
                        });
                        // Add buttons to the card.
                        card.Actions.Add(new HttpAction()
                        {
                            Url = "http://foo.com",
                            Title = "Snooze"
                        });
                        card.Actions.Add(new HttpAction()
                        {
                            Url = "http://foo.com",
                            Title = "I'll be late"
                        });
                        card.Actions.Add(new HttpAction()
                        {
                            Url = "http://foo.com",
                            Title = "Dismiss"
                        });
                        // Create the attachment.
                        Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
                        {
                            ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
                            Content = card
                        };
                        replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(attachment);

                        var reply = await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(replyToConversation);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tested this in bot emulator and works great , thanks

Comment: FYI, if somebody is wondering, you need to install the `Microsoft.AdaptiveCards` nuget package.